# How do I set an UIImage through a animated UIView to another View Controller in SWIFT

Tags: swift, delegates, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller

I currently have `View Controller 1` which has `UIImageView` and a `button` placed over the top, when that `button` is clicked I animate a PopUpViewController which is basically w UIView with buttons, this animates over the top of `View Controller 1`

```
var popViewController : PopUpViewControllerSwift! //popViewController declared in View Controller 1

 @IBAction func changePicture(sender: UIButton) {


            self.popViewController = PopUpViewControllerSwift(nibName: "PopUpViewController_iPhone6", bundle: nil)
            self.popViewController.showInView(self.view, animated: true)
    }
```

The popUpViewController now pops up over the ViewController 1, which then the user presses a button and that presents the ImagePickerController photo library. code here:

```
@IBAction func goToPhotoLibary(sender: UIButton) {

        self.removeAnimate()
        var image = UIImagePickerController()
        image.delegate = self
        image.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
        image.allowsEditing = true
        presentViewController(image, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
```

Now the user picks an image, I then want to be able to place that image in the original `UIImageView` which the user pressed with the button over in `View Controller 1` the code I am using is crashing with the error `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` code used:

```
var VC1 : ProfileViewController! //Reference to View Controller 1

    func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController!, didFinishPickingImage imagePicked: UIImage!, editingInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) {

            self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
             self.VC1.profilePic.image = imagePicked //CRASHES HERE

}
```

I am trying to pass the imagePicked from one ViewController to the next which I assume why it is crashes.

Can anyone add any input into how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: It means a variable which should not be nil is nil, I am guessing it is your imagePicked variable, are you sure when you choose your image it stores the image to the variable? Can we see some code?

Comment: The error is not coming from the imagePicked. The error is coming from the imageView I am trying to place the image into. As the I am trying to reference it to `View Controller 1` it is coming back as nil. So I have set up the reference to `View Controller 1` like so: `var VC1 : ViewController!` and then try to pass it over in the imagePickerController like so:  `self.VC1.profilePic.image = imagePicked` //ERROR HERE

Comment: did u make your UI in storyboard? if sou do you have outlet connected to your imageview? and still can we see your code? its very hard to help without it.

Comment: Ok I have made an edit with code, hope it makes more sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First i would try to set your image then dismiss the controller.

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController!, didFinishPickingImage imagePicked: UIImage!, editingInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) {
    self.VC1.profilePic.image = imagePicked //CRASHES HERE
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

Now what you need to do is to check which variable is nil.

Check you are passing VC1 correctly and is not nil. Check you have profilePic connected to outlet in storyboard(if you are using storyboards). Check if imagePicked is not nil.

You can do it by:

```
if let value = imagePicked{
    println("image is not nil")
}
if let value = self.vc1{
    println("vc1 is not nil")
    if let profilepic = self.vc1.profilePic{
        println("profile pic is not nil")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks its defiantly the VC1 which is nil, Although I don't know what I am doing wrong as I have referenced it like with var `VC1 : ProfileViewController!` As the imageView I am trying to place into is inside the `ProfileViewController`. How do I get  access to that?

Comment: @HenryBrown show the code where you are trying to set your VC1 variable